# Tuple Index Out of Range Error when using random.choice

Tags: python, canvas, random, tkinter, tuples

I seem to running into this "tuple index out of range error" when trying to create rectangle of random sizes. Before, I only had the color set to random and it works. However, when I tried to set the coordinates to random, I get an error and nothing appears on the canvas. Is there something that I am missing?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
import random

canvas = Canvas(root, width=550, height=400)
canvas.pack()

coord = [30, 40, 130, 140]
color = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"]

for j in range(10):
    rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(x0 = random.choice(coord) +j*5,
                                        y0 = random.choice(coord)+j*5,
                                        x1 = random.choice(coord)+j*5,
                                        y1 = random.choice(coord)+j*5,
                                        outline="black",
                                        fill = random.choice(color))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the x0=, y0= ...

```
for j in range(10):
    rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(random.choice(coord) +j*5,
                                    random.choice(coord)+j*5,
                                    random.choice(coord)+j*5,
                                    random.choice(coord)+j*5,
                                    outline="black",
                                    fill = random.choice(color))
```

Comment: Just tried it. Thank you! :D I kinda feel stupid for not realizing that XD